# Difference between "return" and "Break", In Java

Tags: java, return

Whats the difference between "return" and "break" function in java? EXCEPT from the fact that the return function causes execution to exit the subroutine and the break function stops the entire program.

Comment: ‘*the break function exits the entire program*’ Wat?!

Comment: it stops the program from executing.. ;D

Comment: Return and break are not functions, and break doesn’t do what you say it does. Maybe read a tutorial?

Comment: @VardaanSinghRathore No. Where are you getting these things?

Comment: You question clearly depicts lack of research before asking. They are not functions.

Comment: Other than the ways these things are different how are they different?

Answer (score 3):

- `return` is used -

  - to go back to the statement from where the current function was called
  - stop further execution of current function
- `break` is used

  - to exit from loop
  - to exit from switch case

Comment: Break also breaks switch statements which are notably not loops.

Comment: @Tatarize agreed

Answer (score 3):

1) Break statement:

The break statement results in the termination of the loop, it will come out of the loop and stops further iterations.

2) Return statement :

The return statement takes you out of the method. It stops executing the method and returns from the method execution.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement at the end is incorrect. Break will exit a loop, such as for() or while(). You can also use break (name) to break a specifically named loop. Return returns and ends a method.